# Removing all the keys in a dictionary for which their value is 0

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in Python for which I want to remove all the keys that have a value of exactly 0. It's a large dictionary so I cannot copy it here, but lets say this is my dictionary:

```
grades = {mark: 0, Andrew: 0.01, Alex: 0, Sam: 0, Eric: 0.02}
```

The result should look like this:

```
grades = {Andrew: 0.01, Eric: 0.02}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a dict comprehension:

```
grades = {mark: 0, Andrew: 0.01, Alex: 0, Sam: 0, Eric: 0.02}
non_zeros = {k: v for k, v in grades.items() if v != 0}
```

or a `filter`

```
non_zeros = dict(filter(lambda kv: kv[1] != 0, grades.items()))
```

or `del`

```
for k, v in grades.copy().items():
    if v == 0:
        del grades[k]
```

Comment: it can but IMHO it should not. We don't have specs and this as I'm sure you know would also filter out other falsy things as e.g.  `None`

Comment: The last option won't work, one does not simply delete from a dict while iterating over it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `dict` comprehension:

```
grades = {mark: 0, Andrew: 0.01, Alex: 0, Sam: 0, Eric: 0.02}

grades = {k:grades[k] for k in grades if grades[k]}

print(grades)
```

Output:

```
grades = {Andrew: 0.01, Eric: 0.02}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @ted said, you can use dict comprehension, which is probably the best and most compact solution. Here is an alternative way using basic for-each iteration:

```
keys = grades.keys() # Get a list of all the keys

for key in keys:

    if grades[key] == 0: # If the value is 0...

        my_dict.pop(key, None) # Remove the key from the dictionary
```

Comment: This will raise `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`.